# While connecting to mongodb via PHP7.2 laravel, I am getting following error:

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, libmongoc

error : The SCRAM_SHA_256 authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with ENABLE_SSL

i tried to configure and in terminal i found this when i run

> php -i | grep mongo
>
> mongodb libmongoc bundled version => 1.16.2 libmongoc SSL => enabled
> libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL libmongoc crypto => enabled libmongoc
> crypto library => libcrypto libmongoc crypto system profile =>
> disabled libmongoc SASL => enabled libmongoc ICU => disabled libmongoc
> compression => enabled libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
> libmongoc compression zlib => enabled libmongocrypt bundled version =>
> 1.0.3 libmongocrypt crypto => enabled libmongocrypt crypto library => libcrypto mongodb.debug => no value => no value

Comment: Try this: `apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu1).
libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.16).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1g-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libicu64
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: i already tried this

Comment: Check if the solution here can help: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/450

Comment: i dont understand that if i run above command then it show enable but in phpinfo it show disable...

Comment: i already try this @PatricNox

Comment: If it show `enabled` upon install but `disabled` in phpinfo, maybe try restart php?

Comment: i tried many times..i tried pc restart also

Comment: In your php.ini, do you have `extension=mongodb.so`?

Comment: yes i have extension